# How to add names of class and function automatically to my log

Tags: java, android, logging

I'm using `android.util.Log`

```
class Foo
{
  private void boo()
  {
    // This is the basic log of android.
    Log.i("tag", "Start");
  }
}
```

I want the log should be printed `[Foo::boo] Start`.
Can I get the class and function name in Java? Then how do I wrap the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here
**UPDATED**

```
String tag = "[";
tag += this.getClass().toString();
tag += " :: ";
tag += Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().toString();
tag += "]";
Log.i(tag, "Message");
```

`this.getClass().toString()` will return class name as String

**UPDATE**

if function is `static` then use following code

```
String tag = "[";
tag += Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName().toString();
tag += " :: ";
tag += Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().toString();
tag += "]";
Log.i(tag, "Message");
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to use the hardcode for function name.

Comment: @Mayank give a semi colon at the third line to end the statement.

Comment: Much better, thank you. If a function is declared `static`, I think `this` causes a problem, though.

Comment: @Mayank Wouldn't it be better if we did    StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(); and used it to avoid two calls to Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

Answer (score 2):

Get The Current Class Name and Function Name :

```
Log.i(getFunctionName(), "Start");

private String getFunctionName()    
    {    
        StackTraceElement[] sts = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();    
        if(sts == null)    
        {    
            return null;    
        }    
        for(StackTraceElement st : sts)    
        {    
            if(st.isNativeMethod())    
            {    
                continue;    
            }    
            if(st.getClassName().equals(Thread.class.getName()))    
            {    
                continue;    
            }    
            if(st.getClassName().equals(this.getClass().getName()))    
            {    
                continue;    
            }    
            return mClassName + "[ " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": "    
                    +  " "   + st.getMethodName() + " ]";    
        }    
        return null;    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these methods of **java.lang.Class** class

```
getClass().getname() - to get the name of the class
getClass().getMethods() - to get the methods declared in that class.
```

Comment: getClass().getMethods() is sooo badass *.*